# How to add image to pagination buttons in Code Igniter

Tags: php, html, css, image, codeigniter

```
$config['prev_link']='Previous';
                $config['prev_tag_open']='<button type="button" style="border-radius:5px;">';
                $config['prev_tag_close']='</button>';
```

This is the code in the controller. Now, I would like to add an image to this button, how do I do it? if I use an  tag with source set to base_url('path/to/file.png') am getting just an empty square with white border around it. any ideas please and thank you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's okay, I found a way:

```
$config['next_link']='Next<img src="'.base_url("/resources/images/next.png").'" width=20; height=20; style="vertical-align: middle; margin-left: 5px;"/>';
```

This works perfect, thank you guys for your interest.

Answer (score 0):

Put the buttons inside a container (let div) and named with a ID say

```
<div id="pagin">
    <button>1</button>
    <button>2</button>
    ..................
    ..................
    <button>10</button>
</div>
```

Now just use this bellow script.

```
<script>

    var img = <?= base_url('path/to/file.png'); ?>

    $('#pagin button').html('<img src="+img+" alt="image alt text">');
    // This will display the image on every button

    $('#pagin button:first-child').html('<img src="+img+" alt="image alt text">');
    // This will display the image only on the first button

    $('#pagin button:last-child').html('<img src="+img+" alt="image alt text">');
    // This will display the image only on the last button

    $('#pagin button:nth-child(2)').html('<img src="+img+" alt="image alt text">');
    // This will display the image only on the 2nd button

</script>
```

Comment: they are in a div but this won't work for first and last button as they are there only at certain point - if you are on the first page, first button isn't displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CSS like this :

As you are already using inline css you can do this

```
$config['prev_link']='Previous';
                $config['prev_tag_open']='<button type="button" style="border-radius:5px;background-image: url("yourimage.png");">';
                $config['prev_tag_close']='</button>';
```

However i would suggest adding a new class and giving css property to that class.

```
$config['prev_link']='Previous';
                    $config['prev_tag_open']='<button type="button" class="pg-prev">';
                    $config['prev_tag_close']='</button>';
```

CSS FILE

```
 .pg-prev{
    border-radius:5px;
    background-image: url("yourimage.png");
    }
```